# How can I select conditionally some Documents (NotesXspViewEntry) in a dataView (xe:dataView or xe:dynamicViewPanel)

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I need something like this for a time interval:

```
SELECT ( resDueDateBegin >= @Today) & (resDueDateEnd <@Adjust(@Today;0;1;0;0;0;0))
```

where `resDueDateBegin` and `resDueDateEnd` are a `NotesDateTime` object (item or Field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice not to do date filtering in the select statement for the view itself.

Instead you can use the ability to filter the view by a key (or a set of keys). In this case you then use a date range as the filter.

First, make sure that your view is sorted by the two date fields. Then add your filter keys.

The following shows a filter by a date range that I use to filter a view for a dynamic view panel to only show documents within a date range (of x days as specified by compositeData.limitDays) and to filter the view by a certain category (compositeData.catFilter).

```
<xp:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    try {
        var cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE, compositeData.limitDays)
        var endDate = cal.getTime();

        cal.set(1970, 0, 1);
        var startDate = cal.getTime();

        var vDateRange = session.createDateRange(startDate, endDate);

        var v = new java.util.Vector();
        v.addElement(compositeData.catFilter);
        v.addElement(vDateRange);
        return v;                       
    }catch(e){
        print("view filter error: " + e.toString())
    }
}]]></xp:this.keys>
```

Using the above you should be able to make your filtering of two date columns work.

Comment: If you're using a new view, for XPages it may be easier to use text instead of dates. DateTimes can't be serialized, so you can't store them in some properties. Keys may well be fine though.

Comment: @Per Henrik Lausten ->Excellent solution but I need a third Element in the Key-Vector ... see my extension...  result -> 'Car,01.01.70 21:22:50 CET - 18.06.2014 21:22:50 CEDT,17.06.2014 21:22:50 CEDT - 01.01.2100 21:22:50 CET'

Comment: I don't quite understand your example but you should be able to use my example code and just add a 3rd vector element (assuming your view is sorted on all 3 columns)

Comment: @Per Henrik Lausten -> +1 and Thanks for your example. BTW we have here 3 Interval. 1st ist from the Document self between resDueDateBegin and resDueDateEnd. Now the 2nd Interval (vDataRange in Vector) is for intersection with resDueDateBegin and the 3rd Interval (vDataReange2 in Vector ) is for intersection with resDueDateEnd. The result here is : the 1st interval begin bevor 2nd interval ends (resDuedatebegin < endDate) and end after the 3rd interval begins ( resDueDateEnd > startDate2)

Comment: @Per Henrik Lausten, I think this method is more suitable than timeDifference. What do you think?

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question with the specific time/date range problem

Answer (score 0):

here is my extension: (now with right TIME too)

```
    try {
    var cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE, 1)
    cal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    var endDate = cal.getTime();

    cal.set(1970, 0, 1,0,0,0);
    var startDate = cal.getTime();

    var vDateRange = session.createDateRange(startDate, endDate);

    var cal2 = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.add(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0)
    cal2.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    cal2.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal2.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal2.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);

    var startDate2 = cal2.getTime();

    cal2.set(2100, 0, 1,0,0,0);
    var endDate2 = cal2.getTime();

    var vDateRange2 = session.createDateRange(startDate2, endDate2);


    var v = new java.util.Vector();
    v.addElement("Car");
    v.addElement(vDateRange);
    v.addElement(vDateRange2);
    return v;                       
}catch(e){
    print("view filter error: " + e.toString())
}
```

and the result of Vector v is

---

```
Car,01.01.70 00:00:00 CET - 20.06.2014 00:00:00 CEDT,19.06.2014 00:00:00 CEDT - 01.01.2100 00:00:00 CET
```

---

bevor Time adjustment

```
Car,01.01.70 00:00:00 CET - 18.06.2014 23:06:58 CEDT,17.06.2014 23:06:58 CEDT - 01.01.2100 00:00:00 CET
```

but the only trouble that remains here is the TIME

`18.06.2014 21:22:50 CEDT` we need here `18.06.2014 23:59:59 CEDT` or `19.06.2014 00:00:00 CEDT`